# Setting install path based on machine name with WiX

Tags: path, wix, installation, custom-action

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find a simple answer for this, since it seems like it would be a common thing to do.

I'm trying to set the install path based on the machine name of the server it is being installed on, as they have different folder structures.

I'm assuming I need some kind of custom action, but being brand new to WiX, I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start.

I suppose I can just make separate installers for each server (since it's only 3), but it would probably be better practice to just have one that's reusable.

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example? Is it only the root installation directory which depends on the machine name? Or is it entire folder structure underneath which is different for each server? Depending on your answer to this the complexity of the solution might differ...

Comment: Oops, rewriting this comment, because I was thinking of the backup process. For installation, there is one folder in the "middle" that had a different name. So C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\AQSDir\bin and the other two are C:\InetPub\wwwroot\AQSGrabDir\bin, or something along those lines.

Comment: @Relevant so in your example the name of the computer where it is installed to is `AQS`?

Comment: No, that is not the server name. Maybe a better example: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyFolder\bin vs C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyFold\bin

Comment: I've been writing installers for 16 years and I've never had a need to do something like this.  It doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: You've never had one file structure in one server and a different in another? Seems like it would be pretty normal. Maybe we're weird here :-p

Comment: @ChristopherPainter in 16 years writing installers, you've never once... not one time in 16 years had to install something to one directory on one server, and a different directory on another server?

Comment: I've never been asked to tightly couple an installer to a specific machine name.  The relationship is bad. (And that's 18 years now. :) )

Comment: Haha, yes, 18 now :-p Fair enough. I was going through my old questions to see how bad I was way back when. Still don't think this was a bad question, but it was also the only/last time I did installers, so maybe I just still don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the following directory structure in your WiX authoring:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="nametochange">
    <!-- some component -->
    <Directory Id="BinDir" Name="bin">
       <!-- another component -->
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The `INSTALLLOCATION` folder name should differ based on the machine name. You can author a `SetDirectory` element to set the directory path to the desired value (it is a hard code below, just to show the idea):

```
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[%COMPUTERNAME]" />
```

The `SetDirectory` element schedules the underlying custom action properly. Note the way environment variable is referenced in WiX: `[%COMPUTERNAME]`. If you target Windows Installer 4.0+, you can rely on the special property `ComputerName`.

**Update**: depending on the exact requirements, you can go further and experiment:

```
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FolderA">ComputerName = Server1</SetDirectory>
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FolderB">ComputerName = Server2</SetDirectory>
<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FolderC">ComputerName = Server3</SetDirectory>
```

etc.

Comment: While this seems much simpler than a managed code custom action type solution, it looks like this would be dependent on the folder name being the same as the machine name, which is not the case. For example, For server named "Server1", it would go into "FolderA" and "Server2" would go to "FolderB".

Comment: I've updated my answer with more sample data. If you get the idea, experiment to get the desired behavior.